# Windows service environment - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: powershell, registry, windows-server-2012, regedit

I'm installing my own Windows service. It requires it's own Environment. No tool that I know handles it, so I manually edit registry.

I have service installation script written in PowerShell, so my first idea was to do this:

```
New-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\MyService" -Name Environment -Value "EnvVar=value" -PropertyType MultiString
```

The problem is, while the key appears int the registry, it is *not used* by my service, even after powercycle.

Experimenting, I found out that if I edit it in regedit, it works and the key is used by my service. So, I hanged it to this:

```
Invoke-Expression "reg.exe add ""HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\$name"" /v ""Environment"" /d ""EnvVar=value"" /t REG_MULTI_SZ /f"
```

and now it works :D

Whats wrong with my usage of `New-ItemProperty`? I'm doing everything as admin, and I'm avare of 64/32bit issues (and I don't think they apply here - my software is 64bit, windows is 64bit, everything is 64bit :))

It adds the key to the registry but it is not used, while adding the same key using `regedit.exe` or `reg.exe` works fine. Maybe I'm hitting some bug? (OS: Windows Server 2012, 64bit)

Comment: hm, you could try to use ProcessMonitor and check whether the application tries to read the key

Comment: Reg ACLs are only set until the level of the service itself. I checked your examples and they create indeed the same subentries. Did you already try to revert your changes and see if the PS command may work in the meantime? often there are changes that you may have been not aware of

Comment: Can't reproduce. Both commands created identical values for me, so I don't see why one approach would work while the other would not. Do you have UAC (registry virtualization in particular) enabled?